# spaces in for /f forfiles batch not working

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, spaces

I'm trying to make an automated old file deleting script, this is what I've come up with so far.

First I make an input file for user home dirs.

Command:

```
dir downloads /s /b echo > input.txt
```

It fills the .txt file like this:

```
F:\HomeDirs\a.Durge\Mijn Documenten\Downloads
F:\HomeDirs\a.eimers\Mijn Documenten\Downloads
F:\HomeDirs\a.eimers\system\Downloads
F:\HomeDirs\a.gacem\system\Downloads
```

After the input file has completed to fill up i want this as input to delete files older than 30 days in folders named downloads

```
FOR /f %%G in (input.txt) DO forfiles /p %%G /C "cmd /c del %%G\*.* /q" /D -30
```

This works to a certain extent, the filepaths that contain spaces aren't affected proccessed.

I tried adding quotes around the paths but I think I'm goofing up somewhere.

This is the error the batch gives me:

```
D:\Scripts>forfiles /p "F:\HomeDirs\a.Durge\Mijn /C "cmd /c del "F:\HomeDirs\a.Durge\Mijn\*.* /q" /D -30
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'F:\HomeDirs\a.Durge\Mijn\*.* /q'.
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.
```

Filepaths that dont contain the spaces are processed properly.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for /f` command is using `space` as a delimiter (`space` and `tab` are the default delimiters).

So `F:\HomeDirs\a.Durge\Mijn Documenten\Downloads` will return two tokens.

```
F:\HomeDirs\a.Durge\Mijn 
Documenten\Downloads
```

To stop this happening add `"delims="` (use no delimiters at all) to your command:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (input.txt) DO forfiles /p %%G /C "cmd /c del %%G\*.* /q" /D -30
```

You can further simplify things by using a different type of `for` which loops against the output of another command (removing the need for an intermediate file), combining both commands in one line:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir downloads /s /b') DO forfiles /p %%G /C "cmd /c del %%G\*.* /q" /D -30
```

See [FOR /F Loop command: against the results of another command.](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much David for your very complete answer to my question, much appreciated !

Comment: will this require the script to be of the F drive? i ask because it now states ('dir downloads /s /b')

Comment: Yes, you would need to be on drive f just like when you run your original command that creates input.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around %%G.

```
FOR /f %%G in (input.txt) DO forfiles /p "%%G" /C "cmd /c del %%G\*.* /q" /D -30
```

Comment: Hi SomethingDark, ty for trying to help me out! i added the quotes around %%G and i tested the script again. it gives me this output: 
D:\Scripts>forfiles /p "F:\HomeDirs\a.Durge\Mijn" /C "cmd /c del F:\HomeDirs\a.Durge\Mijn\*.* /q" /D -30
ERROR: The specified directory does not exist.

Comment: @Sydney - sounds like F:\HomeDirs\a.Durge\Mijn isn't a directory that can be found on your computer

Answer (score 0):

Put "tokens=*" in the "for /f"

```
 For /f "tokens=*"
```

So you get the whole line not just the first "token" up to the space